# Angular4 @Input() vs Component.inputs array

Tags: angular

From my understanding using

```
@Input() name: string;
```

And using the inputs array in the Component decorator as follows

```
@Component({
            ...
            inputs: ['bankName', 'id: account-id']
          })
```

Is basically the same. They both specify a binding input attribute on the component/directive element. 
Is there any difference between the two?
If so whats the difference and when should each of them be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [official style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#decorate-input-and-output-properties):

> Do use the **@Input()** and **@Output()** class decorators instead of the **inputs** and **outputs** properties of the **@Directive** and **@Component** metadata

Answering your question there is no real difference between two approaches rather than readability and maintainability of your code. It's common practice to avoid using `inputs` and `outputs` properties.

Comment: Thanks should of went straight to the style guide instead of trying to search for this on google.